# Show specific amount of elements from observableArray and hide rest

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I want to show for example 10 items from my `observableArray` and hide rest of them, and when I add a new element to beginning of array hide the 10Th element, and user to be able to click show more items.

### Here are my current markups

**Javascript:**

```
var itemViewModel = {
    item: {},
    isLoaded: ko.observable(false),
    comments: ko.observableArray([]),
    loadcontent: function (getID) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/item/details/' + getID,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                itemViewModel.item = data;
                itemViewModel.comments([]);
                $.each(data.Comments, function (index, thisComment) {
                    itemViewModel.comments.push(thisComment);
                });
                itemViewModel.comments.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return new Date(a.DateTime) == new Date(b.DateTime)
                        ? 0 : (new Date(a.DateTime) < new Date(b.DateTime) ? 
                        1 : -1)
                });
                itemViewModel.isLoaded(true);
                itemDetailBindings();
            }
        });
    },
    showComment: function (ele) {
        if (ele.nodeType === 1) $(ele).hide().fadeIn()
    }
};
//Item detail element bindings
var itemDetailBindings = function () {
    // Add auto expand to textarea
    $('#this-text-is-comment').TextAreaExpander(50, 200);
    //Add comment
    $('#this-text-is-comment').bind('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
                addComment($("#this-text-is-comment").val(), $("#hidden-item-id").val());
                $(this).val('');
            };
        }
    });
};
var addComment = function (cText, getID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/comment/create',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { comment1: cText, itemid: getID },
        success: function (data) {
            itemViewModel.comments.splice(0, 0, data);
        }
        /*error: function (xhr, status) {
        switch (status) {
        case 404:
        alert('File not found');
        break;
        case 500:
        alert('Server error');
        break;
        case 0:
        alert('Request aborted');
        break;
        default:
        alert('Unknown error ' + status);
        }
        }*/
    });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="comment-list clearfix" data-bind="template: {foreach: comments, afterAdd: showComment }">
    <div class="comment-container clearfix">
        <div class="left-side">
            <img src="../../content/u/2012.08.17.634808075593134766.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="right-side clearfix">
            <div class="top">
                <span class="user-name" data-bind="text: User.FullName"></span><span class="time-posted"
                    data-bind="text: $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(DateTime))"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="middle clearfix">
                <div class="body">
                    <p data-bind="text: Comment1">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**For staters:** I have no clue how can I do that in ko.js

Comment: Bind to a separate observableArray which you maintain as a list of 10 items?

Comment: @ChrisMoutray Ok but I would like user to be able to click show more comments and it would show 20 comments

Comment: I don't know the answer but as a side-note on good resources for working with knockout and arrays/collections: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections and http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=knockout

Comment: @FrançoisWahl ok I have an idea, I could do `visible: elementPosition < allowedToShow; var allowedTOshow = 10;` but how could I find out witch element is it or witch position it represents, I'm not very familiar with `observableArray's`

Comment: @skmasq: I'm not trying to be smart but as I don't know the answer myself, maybe something in the documentation could help you: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I happened upon [computed filtered arrays](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/07/knockout-js-pro-tips-working-with-observable-arrays/) (see tip2) but after thinking this through you can do this simply by combining [Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) and [Javascript `slice()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).

In this following example you would bind to the `filteredComments`. `self.comments()` is the main list of comments, the array is *sorted* and then *sliced* to show the first # number of comments (`self.commentsShown()`).

```
self.filteredComments = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.comments()
        .sort(compareComments) // important to sort before slicing
        .slice(0, self.commentsShown());
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/LsxCm/) for a full working example. It allows for sorted/filtered list of comments, add to to start of comments array (not filtered array) and *show more*.

Comment: This is what I really wanted. Thank you, this is accepted one now.

Comment: Where should I add sort function, that is when?

Comment: @skmasq i've improved my answer to include *sort* also simplified the filtering to make use of *slice* - looks cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I couldn't find how to access the `observableArray` here is my solution.

`visible: $parent.comments.indexOf($data) < 2`

Comment: What about using `$index`?  `visible: $index() < 10`